# How to use a Dynamic List Type of SObject getted by ID

Tags: apex, sobject, list, dynamic, sobjecttype

I'm trying to do a Dynamic List of a SObject gutted from an ID.
My goal is SEND a SObject info via mail. (Opportunity, Case...)

From a list of selected records, I send by argument their IDs with this Javascript Button:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/27.0/apex.js")}
  var url = parent.location.href;
  var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Opportunity)};
  if (records[0] == null) {
    alert("Please select at least one record.");
  } else if (records.length > 10) {
    alert("Please select less than 10 records.");
  } else {
    alert("Selected: " + records.length + " records.");
    sforce.apex.execute("myClass ","myMethod",{idArrays:records});
  }
  parent.location.href = url;
```

And this is my Class Code:

```
global class myClass {

  WebService static void myMethod(list <String> 
    ID myId = Id.valueOf(idArrays[0]);
    // In this case, mySObject return SObject Opportunity
    Schema.sObjectType mySObject = myId.getSObjectType(); 

    List<mySObject> lSelected = new List<mySObject
    lSelected = Database.query('SELECT Name, Account.Name FROM ' + mySObject + ' WHERE id = :idArrays');
    for (mySObject ms :lSelected){
      //Here call another class with ms records.
      clsSendEmail.testMail(address, subject, body);
    }
  }
}
```

Can I use List like that? Or how. If I try to do:

```
    List<SObject> lSelected = new List <SObject>();
    lSelected = Database.query('SELECT.......');
    for (SObject ms :lSelected){
        clsSendEmail.testMail(address, subject, body); 
//if here try to get ms.Name... or some data, returns Error: 'Field expression not allowed for generic SObject'
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can get a value using the [SObject.get method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get). So in you case `String name = (String) ms.get('Name');` will give you the name; the field will have to have been included in the query too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option won't work because you can't use a variable as a type parameter,  even if the variable holds a SObjectType.

How were you retrieving the name in the second option? ms.Name won't compile, because not all Sobjecy  types  have a name field, but md.get ("name") should work so long as the passed in object has one.